# How to use Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource with dynamic datasources?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am working in a project using Spring, Spring Data JPA, Spring Security, Primefaces...

I was following [this tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) about dynamic datasource routing with spring.

In this tutorial, you can only achieve dynamic datasource switching between a pre-defined datasources.

Here is a snippet of my code :

**springContext-jpa.xml**

```
<bean id="dsCgWeb1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName.Cargest_web}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url.Cargest_web}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username.Cargest_web}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password.Cargest_web}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dsCgWeb2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    // same properties, different values ..
</bean>

<!--  Generic Datasource [Default : dsCargestWeb1]  -->
<bean id="dsCgWeb" class="com.cargest.custom.CargestRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value-ref="dsCgWeb1" />
            <entry key="2" value-ref="dsCgWeb2" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="dsCgWeb1" />
</bean>
```

What i want to do is to make the **targetDataSources** map dynamic same as its elements too.

In other words, i want to fetch a certain database table, use properties stored in that table to create my datasources then put them in a map like **targetDataSources**.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I had similar functionality to implement. In my case it was many data sources created on runtime with users, passwords and jdbc urls read from 'env' database. So what I did was to create my own implementation of DataSource interface that keeps static concurrent map field where I store all dynamically created datasource instances and ThreadLocal varaiable that holds information about current datasource being used by particular thread.

Comment: Does your solution work without any problems ? if so, it's exactly what i need. Can you provide your custom Datasource implementation ? thanks :)

Comment: Sure it works :) However I cannot share the code the way it is now. I will do my best to simplify it to the form I could share it and put on github and share the link to it.

Comment: @GrzegorzSolecki can you please share the code for problem that you describe above ?? if u can then please share link

Answer (score 16):

Nothing in `AbstractRoutingDataSource` forces you to use a static map of `DataSourceS`. It is up to you to contruct a bean implementing `Map<Object, Object>`, where key is what you use to select the `DataSource`, and value is a `DataSource` or (by default) a String referencing a JNDI defined data source. You can even modify it dynamically since, as the map is stored in memory, `AbstractRoutingDataSource` does no caching.

I have no full example code. But here is what I can imagine. In a web application, you have one database per client, all with same structure - ok, it would be a strange design, say it is just for the example. At login time, the application creates the datasource for the client and stores it in a map indexed by sessionId - The map is a bean in root context named `dataSources`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSources");
Map<String, DataSource> sources;

// I assume url, user and password have been found from connected user
// I use DriverManagerDataSource for the example because it is simple to setup
DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, user, password);
sources.put(request.getSession.getId(), dataSource);
```

You also need a session listener to cleanup `dataSources` in its `destroy` method

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSources");
Map<String, DataSource> sources;

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)  {
    // eventually cleanup the DataSource if appropriate (nothing to do for DriverManagerDataSource ...)
    sources.remove(se.getSession.getId());
}
```

The routing datasource could be like :

```
public class SessionRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)
                RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        return request.getSession().getId();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSources")
    public void setDataSources(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
        setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
}
```

I have not tested anything because it would be a lot of work to setting the different database, but I thing that it should be Ok. In real world there would not be a different data source per session but one per user with a count of session per user but as I said it is an over simplified example.

Comment: This is almost working. You need to invoke to afterPropertiesSet(); after setTargetDataSources(dataSources); so the datasources are reloaded. As well I would suggest to run it in a syncrhonized block if this will be running in a multithreaded env and this is modifying a single instance of an object in the system.

Comment: The only disadvantage is that every time the afterPropertiesSet is called, it will create new DataSource objects for every data source in the target.

Comment: Which also means you can't add datasources in real-time, because AbstractRoutingDataSource holds its own separate map of resolved datasources.

Answer (score 1):

The datasource used by a thread might change from time to time.
Should pay attention to concurrency, applications might get concurrency issues in concurrent environment.
[thread-bound AbstractRoutingDataSource sample](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with AbstractRoutingDataSource and keeping the information in the thread-local Variable. Here is a beautiful working example you can refer to:
[Multi-tenancy: Managing multiple datasources with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759672/multi-tenancy-managing-multiple-datasources-with-spring-data-jpa/)