# How to create and maintain one jdbc connection per user in web app (Spring/Vaadin)?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, apache-commons-dbcp

How to create an application which can handle thousand of jdbc connection at runtime without implementing connection pool ? AFAIK to establish connection pool, we need **username**, **passowrd** and required **dbinstance url** but here all of them will be provided at runtime to connect particular database, and there would be more than 1000 user at one time to connect to set of databases.(memory intensive !)
So typically it going to be like this:

**Users**: User-A,User-B,User-C.....User-n
**db**:  DB1, DB2, DB3....DBn

Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve this task ?
I only have one thing in my mind, i.e. to create single connection with each session and use it whereever required specific to that user.

I've used Apache Commons DBCP2 for connection pooling, MyBatis-Spring implementation, Spring and Vaadin for different application but not sure if anyone of them gonna help me !

Comment: for an idea, can http://stackoverflow.com/a/26177079/2231632 help?

Comment: didn't get any clue... probably it explain the same thing around AbstractRoutingDataSource.. but unable to understand Map thing.

Comment: What he explains is that you don't have to define the datasource in xml (for AbstractRoutingDataSource) rather define it dynamically and clean it up accordingly. the example shows tying it to a user's session. If you have to change the username/password for you entire connection pool, you might have to get the datasource from Spring context, close/destroy the underlying pool and create a new one with the new username/password and set it back to the datasource. (really really crooked, people - don't hurt me!) But if you want to do it for one connection in the pool, i don't think you can do it.

Comment: @agpt can you always connect as one user (webserver) and then SET ROLE to the real user? Which DB?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Its Oracle database, where around 2K user should be login randomly. each user has assigned specific role to access particular table in database. Its kind of db admin tool but much more specific in terms of access role. I dont know if using spring would help in this case. because each user need to have one authorized connection with db.

Comment: Guys... (@NeilMcGuigan) I have updated / rephrase my question again. Please dont hurt me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to settle down with following approach. Though I am not sure if its a good approach.

I created a `SqlSessionFactory` by providing `DataSource` with dynamic Username, Password and Database.

```
public SqlSessionFactory build() throws IOException, SQLException
{       
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setURL(this.dbUrl);
    dataSource.setUser(this.dbUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(this.dbPassword);
    dataSource.setDriverType(properties.getProperty("db.driver"));
    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
    Environment environment = new Environment(properties.getProperty("db.environment"), transactionFactory, dataSource);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
    configuration.addMappers("com.app.dao");
    SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
    // final test connection to db
    sessionFactory.openSession().getConnection();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Then I am getting one `SqlSession` out of factory:

```
SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

and I am setting it across Vaadin session :(, so that it would be available throughout session. Hence I can use it whenever I need by taking it from session.

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(SqlSession.class,session);
```

I am discarding it when logout:

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(SqlSession.class, null);
```

I feel its dirty and may create memory issue. but didn't find any other easy solution. Please feel free to comment or answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

Oracle supports [proxy authentication](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3910651/Using-Proxy-Authentication-Methods-in-Oracle-Database-11g.htm). It would work something like this:

1. setup limited rights user for your application (say `webgui`)
2. connect to database as `webgui` (w connection pooling)
3. authenticate the real user (say `JoeSmith`) by simply trying to connect as him (`JoeSmith`/`password`), perhaps w a second connection
4. in first connection change user to `JoeSmith` (not sure what oracle syntax is, in postgres it's SET ROLE)
5. reset user at end of database session

EclipseLink has a `postAcquireClientSession` method, not sure about MyBatis

You might have to wipe any caching in your ORM if it uses it