# Replace old data source with new one in the Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

There is Spring Boot application connected to two databases:

1. db_1 - contains all business logic;
2. db_2 - contains application configurations.

**Issue** 
User should be able to change configurations : db_host, db_user, db_password, db_type. And application will automatically disconnect from the db_1 and connect to another one with the same table schema.

**Question** 
How to remove old data source and create new one at the run time using Spring Boot.

Comment: Something similar I did a year ago, but having 2 mains separately in the first one I could modify a properties so that when I wanted to execute 1 query the second application will load the datasource from this properties, maybe it is not the cleanest solution but it could be worth it PD: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: [How to use Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource with dynamic datasources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176439/how-to-use-spring-abstractroutingdatasource-with-dynamic-datasources/26177079#26177079)