# How to programatically change databases in Spring 3.x with one DataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I'm looking to see the complete working example code in spring MVC 3.x version what's the best way to use one DataSources in Spring but be able to switch the database from within the Java code? Below are my two DataSources and they go to the same database server but different databases.

```
<bean id="ds_hydhccj" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"></property>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
        <property name="password" value="postgres"></property>
    </bean>
```

How to be able to use one data source and switch databases dynamically when I select the dropdown option from the front end that is the dbname which i want to pass it url?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get application context, in your case you can do it in two ways

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")
```

or

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

then,you

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("ds_hydhccj");
```

If you are using framework like e.g hibernate, I recommend you to create two separate entity managers which hold two different connections.

Comment: It is a web-based application implemented in spring MVC 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractRoutingDataSource` should be your friend. It allows to setup one single bean in the Spring ApplicationContext with the machinery to switch it to one of n actual datasources.

You can find a simple example in that other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26176439/3545273)