# How to have multiple db connection simultaneously and Add new DB during runtime in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I think this is some advanced stuff and
I have very little Knowledge in spring boot

We are migrating our project to spring boot.In this web app we're connecting to some organization databases (2) know in  advance and customer databases which is not known initially. Using API we will pass the customer database name.API may be called simultaneously.So connection to different databases are needed.

I wrote something which is working but i not the correct way to do

Is it Ok to Use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean not as a bean?

How can i create repository with this ?

Is there a better way?

```
public class ConfigClass {
    public static SortedMap<String, WeakReference<EntityManagerFactory>> factoryMap = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<String, WeakReference<EntityManagerFactory>>());


    public DataSource getDataSource(String dbname)
    {
        
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("root")
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbname)
                .password("root")
                .build();
    }


    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (DataSource dataSource) {

        System.out.println(dataSource);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.entity");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getDataSource().getConnection());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        System.out.println(entityManagerFactory);
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
    public EntityManager getEM(String dbname) throws SQLException {

        if(factoryMap.containsKey(dbname)&&factoryMap.get(dbname).get()!=null) {
            System.out.println("From factoryMap");
            return factoryMap.get(dbname).get().createEntityManager();
        }
        System.out.println("creating Entitymanagerfactory");
        factoryMap.put(dbname,new WeakReference<>( getEntityManagerFactory(getLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(getDataSource(dbname)))));
        return factoryMap.get(dbname).get().createEntityManager();
    }


   
}
```

Comment: Search on: spring boot multi tenant database - [this](https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa#1-separate-database) should be a good start.  And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177079/6650475) should help with the dynamic runtime configuration.

Comment: i couldn't find anything that tells about multiple database connection at the same time